# Is it possible to use a shorter helper function instead of typeof something !== "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, undefined

This works fine

```
var isRenderer = typeof process !== "undefined" && process.type === "renderer";
```

I don't like having those typeof checks all over my code, so I tried writing a helper function. But using it causes a reference error to be thrown

```
var isRenderer = !isUndefined(process) && process.type === "renderer";

function isUndefined(val) {
  return typeof val === "undefined";
}
```

I have two questions:

- Why does the helper function I wrote not work?
- Is it possible to write a helper function to replace the typeof checks?

Comment: You should ask yourself why you are in the situation of needing to check for undefined variables regularly in the first place.

Comment: not really a solution per se, but just adding a `var process` in isRenderer or higher's scope would be enough to resolve the problem, as it'll get hoisted anyways.  Then you could just check process for truthiness.  Still would mask what is probably an underlying problem with abusing globals excessively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't like having those typeof checks all over my code, so I tried writing a helper function. But using it causes a reference error to be thrown

If you got an error with your function, that tells us that `process` is an undeclared identifier, not just a variable/parameter whose value is `undefined`. You can use `typeof` on an undeclared identifier, but you can't read its value.

Unfortunately, you can't write a function to do what you've outlined. The closest you can come is:

```
var isRenderer = !isUndefined(typeof process) && process.type === "renderer";

function isUndefined(type) {
  return type === "undefined";
}
```

Note that it still needs `typeof` at the point where you're calling it. But at least it avoids the opportunity of a silent logic error if you had a typo in `"undefined"` (as I often do).

The best course is to look at the reasons you would be trying to use an undeclared identifier and address those. But barring doing that, you'll need the `typeof` check.

---

If `process` were a declared identifier but it had the value `undefined`, your function would have worked. But in that scenario, you soon wouldn't need it because of [*optional chaining*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). That's a new feature in the ES2020 specification that's in modern JavaScript environments (Chrome v80+, Firefox v74+, Safari 13.1+) and can be used with older JavaScript environments if you transpile (for instance, with Babel). Then your statement would look like this:

```
// ONLY WORKS IF `process` IS DECLARED
var isRenderer = process?.type === "renderer";
```

`isRenderer` would be `false` if `process` were declared but had the value `undefined` or `null`, because `process?.type` would evaluate to `undefined`, and `undefined === "renderer"` is false.

But again, that won't work in the situation you have, since `process` is an undeclared identifier.

Comment: You might also want to look into new feature of optional chaining which is available in ES2020.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 - That won't help with the above, for the same reason that the OP's function didn't work. `process?.type` will throw a ReferenceError if `process` is an undeclared identifier. I had thought to add a note about that to the answer, then thought it might be confusing. Maybe I should though.

Answer (score 1):

As has been answered and commented, you can't pass an undeclared variable to a function without an error being generated when trying to read the variable to pass it as an argument.

However, simply checking that `process` is defined before checking its properties fails if `process` is `null`. The solution I normally use and would suggest is to check for an object value and then check it's not `null`:

```
if(typeof process === "object" && process && process.type === "renderer")
```

is generally safer.