# How to write a typeof val === "undefined" helper function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, undefined

I have the following function in JavaScript:

```
function isUndefined(type) {
  return type === "undefined";
}
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320137/1283776

Here is an example of it being called:

```
var isRenderer = !isUndefined(typeof process) && process.type === "renderer";
```

How can I rewrite that function in TypeScript and have the same effect on type narrowing after calling it as I would have if I used `typeof process !== "undefined"` directly.

Here is my best non-working attempt.

```
export function isUndefined<T>(type: T): type is "undefined" {
  return type === "undefined";
}
```

> This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T' and 'string' have no overlap.

Comment: `type` is string, not `T` because you send `typeof process`.

Comment: undefined is it's own type in typescript, remove the quotes around it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If you're always passing in the variable as (typeof variable) then you'll always be passing in a string, so you can set the type for the input parameter to be a string.

A better solution off of this might be just passing in the variable, then could return variable === undefined rather than calling typeof. Note, this does not check if its null, only undefined. To check both null and undefined you would 
return variable == null.